# Regular expression for validation MM/YY with YY greater or equal to current year

Tags: regex, validation

I want to validate card expiration date on format `MM/YY`, `MM` should have values from `01` to `12` and `YY` from `19` to `99`.

This is my code:

`^(0[1-9]|10|11|12)/1[9]|2[0-9]{2}$`

The `MM` part seems to work fine but the `YY` doesn't. It only take `19` as valid but also if I add new digits after that it says it's valid.

I was expecting to not validate if there are more than 2 digits for `YY` because of `{2}`.

How should it be changed in order to validate all years from `19` to `99` ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, still doesn't work. I checked for `11/19`, `11/20` and fails for both. I've tested it here https://regex101.com/ but still not working

Comment: You missed the grouping construct anyway, `1[9]|2[0-9]` must be wrapped with a group, `(1[9]|2[0-9])`. The `{2}` can be removed. `^(0[1-9]|10|11|12)\/(1[9]|2[0-9])$` already [works](https://regex101.com/r/PSGWTg/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may works for your need:

```
^(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:19|[2-9][0-9])$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/FrZJKU/1

Explanation:

```
^               Line start with...
 (?:            > Start non-capturing group
    0[1-9]      January to September
          |     OR
    1[0-2]      October to December
  )             > End non-capturing group
\/              literal '/'
  (?:           > Start non-capturing group
     19         literal '19'
       |        OR
     [2-9][0-9] 20 to 99
  )             > End non-capturing group
$               line must end with 20 to 99
```

Comment: A good answer should include a summary of how you solved the problem, so that readers can learn the general principle and apply it to other examples, rather than just copy and pasting the solution.

Comment: I agree. I added a brief explanation about how this regex works

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have a missing set of brackets around the year part, so the `|` operator will split the whole pattern, like this:

- `^(0[1-9]|10|11|12)/1[9]`
- or
- `2[0-9]{2}$`

Secondly, your year pattern is asking for a 2 followed by 2 digits (the `{2}` modifier) so will match 200, 299, etc. You actually want a single digit in the range 2 to 9 followed by a single digit 0 to 9: `[2-9][0-9]`

Finally, there's no need to put square brackets around the 9; it doesn't matter, but it makes it harder to read for no purpose.

Putting those fixes together:

```
^(0[1-9]|10|11|12)/(19|[2-9][0-9])$
```